# Table with horizontal bar chart in ggplot2 or plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Is there a ggplot2 extension package that can produce a table/horizontal bar chart viz similar to one on Fivethirty Eight. Ideally I would like the ability to add a second or even third bar chart and additional text columns.

I've been Googlging and looking at ggplot chart galleries, but haven't come across anything yet.

[image]

Comment: Package requests are off-topic, but e.g. see here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8242/plotting-sparklines-in-r. Or a dupe on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841221/add-sparkline-graph-to-a-table

Comment: Or see this paper: https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2015-1/templ-kowarik-meindl.pdf

Comment: https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/building-twitter-followers.html

Answer (score 5):

A workaround would be to use the `DT` package. This renders an *HTML*  table, but depending on your needs you could use this one. In `RStudio` you can also easily export the table to any picture format:

```
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(CANDIDATE = c("Biden", "Sanders", "Gabbard", "O'Rourke",
                                "Warren", "Yang", "Buttigieg", "Castro", 
                                "Harris", "Klobuchar", "Booker", "Steyer"),
                  EXCLUSIVE = c(218, 100, 11, 29, 107, 14, 27, 6, 23, 8, 4, 1), 
                  TOTAL     = c(996, 683, 83, 245, 917, 187, 437, 105, 433, 180, 201, 84), 
                  SHARE     = c(21.9, 14.6, 13.1, 11.7, 11.6, 7.4, 6.2, 
                                5.7, 5.2, 4.2, 2.2, 1.4) / 100)

datatable(dat, options = list(
  columnDefs = list(list(className = "dt-left", targets = 4)))) %>%
  formatPercentage("SHARE", 1) %>%
  formatStyle("SHARE",
              background = styleColorBar(dat$SHARE, "steelblue", -90), backgroundPosition = "left")
```

[image]